# Vertical "moving" text on a LCD-display

Tags: c++, arduino

> **Following idea:**
>
> You have a LCD-display with 2 rows.
>
> [image]
>
> 1. You write the first line of a "text" to the second row. Then you clean the screen.
> 2. After a delay you write the first line to the first row and a the second line of the text to the second row. Then follows another clean
>      and delay.
> 3. Then you write the second line to the first row and the third line to the second row. And so on ...
>
> When the end of the text is reached the whole process starts again
>   from the beginning.
>
> That way the impression of an "vertical moving" text is accomplished.

The code I have written:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setDisplay(String lineValue, int lineNumber, int waitUntilClear, boolean clearScreen) {
  lcd.setCursor(0, lineNumber),
  lcd.print(lineValue); 

  delay(waitUntilClear);

  if (clearScreen == true) {
   lcd.clear(); 
  }
}

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {
  const int DELAY = 3000;
  const int COUNT_ELEMENTS = 12;

  String messages[COUNT_ELEMENTS] = {
    "",
    "Furniture Store",
    " MEYER & MILLER",
    "",
    "  Contact us!",
    "",
    " -- Email ----- ",
    "demo@example.com",
    "",
    " -- Phone ----- ",
    " 000 123456",
    ""
  };

  for (int i = 0; i < COUNT_ELEMENTS - 1; i++) {
    setDisplay(messages[i], 0, 0, false);
    setDisplay(messages[i + 1], 1, DELAY, true);
  } 
}
```

It works fine and by using an additional function I could avoid code redundancies mostly. If someone has an idea how to improve my code or even doing it completely different in a better way, then I would appreciate his/her comment or answer.

Comment: You can [include images](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in questions.

Comment: @yuri Thanks for the tipp and the URL. It's awesome.

Comment: From phone then just comment. Note that `waitUntilClear` is always 0 when `clearScreen` is `false` then boolean flag is redundant. More than that...you should directly accept both lines (or an array with a `startIndex` if you plan to reuse this with different displays). Finally I see too many magic numbers.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks a big bunch for your hints. I'm a beginner with C++ and Arduino. This knowledge will be valuable for the time to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitUntilClear` is always `0` when `clearScreen` is `false` then boolean flag is redundant:

```
void setDisplay(String lineValue, int lineNumber, unsigned long msToWaitBeforeClear) {
  lcd.setCursor(0, lineNumber),
  lcd.print(lineValue); 

  if (msToWaitBeforeClear > 0) {
   delay(msToWaitBeforeClear);
   lcd.clear(); 
  }
}
```

Note that `delay()` accepts `unsigned long` instead of `int` then our parameter should match its type (does it make sense to have a negative delay?)

Now is (should be) clearer that we're calling `setDisplay()` twice but it's easier to simply call it with the index of the current line:

```
void displayPage(String messages[], size_t startIndex) {
  for (int8_t rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUMBER_OF_DISPLAY_LINES; ++rowIndex) {
      lcd.setCursor(0, rowIndex),
      lcd.print(messages[startIndex + rowIndex]); 
  }

   delay(DELAY_BETWEEN_PAGES_IN_MS);
   lcd.clear(); 
}
```

Used as:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < COUNT_ELEMENTS - 1; ++i) {
  displayPage(messages, i);
}
```

Now it's time to remove those magic numbers in `setup()` and `lcd` declaration. I'd also suggest to move all *global* constants to the very top, outside functions (probably in a separate file). It's what you want to change to configure your display and it's better if you don't have to search them buried inside code.

One small note: if you manually unroll the loop over `NUMBER_OF_DISPLAY_ROWS` then you can skip the first call to `setCursor()` because `clear()` already do it for you:

```
void displayPage(String messages[], size_t startIndex) {
    lcd.print(messages[startIndex]); 
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1),
    lcd.print(messages[startIndex + 1]); 

    delay(DELAY_BETWEEN_PAGES_IN_MS);
    lcd.clear(); 
}
```